# Steganography in java isn't working

Tags: java, image-processing, bitmap, bit-manipulation, steganography

I'm currently trying to create a steganography program in java but I have no idea where I've went wrong.

I attempt to encode a string ("hello"), of which i store the length of the string as a 32 bit integer at the start of the pixel array.

When I decode the newly created image I instead get a payload of length 17 and I have no idea.
So:

- What have I done wrong?
- How do I fix this?

**Code Below:**

```
public class Steganography{

/*
 *Steganography Empty Constructor
 */
private byte[] payload;
private BufferedImage image;

public static int headerLength=32;

public Steganography(String payload, String coverimage) throws IOException {
    this.payload = payload.getBytes();
    this.image = ImageIO.read(new File(coverimage));


}

//each element of array returned represnts an RGB component
public int[] getPixels(BufferedImage image){
    byte[] imagebytes = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

    int[] pixels = new int[imagebytes.length];

    for(int i=0; i<imagebytes.length; i++){
        pixels[i] = unsignedToBytes(imagebytes[i]);
    }
    return pixels;

}

public void encode() throws IOException {

    //get the pixels
    int[] pixels = getPixels(image);


    //get length of message and encode into image
    byte[] payloadLength = new byte[]{0,0,0, (byte)(payload.length & 0x000000FF)};



    System.out.println("payload length:\t" + payload.length);

        //encode the header information
    System.out.print("Encoding header...");
    pixels = encode_text(pixels, payloadLength, 0);
    System.out.println("done!");

    //now encode the actual payload message
    //pixels = encode_text(pixels, payload, 40);




    //save the image
    saveImage(pixels);
}

public void decode(){

    System.out.println("Decoding...");
    //get the pixels
    int[] pixels = getPixels(this.image);

    int payloadLength = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<32; ++i) {
        System.out.print(getLSB(pixels[i]));
        payloadLength = (payloadLength << 1) | getLSB(pixels[i]);
    }
    //get length of message from the first 32 bytes
    System.out.println("printing Payload Length: "+payloadLength);


    //read first 4 bytes (java integer is 4 bytes long)




    //output the message
}


//encode payload into cover-image
private int[] encode_text(int[] image, byte[] payload, int offset) {


    int imageCursor = offset;
    for(int i=0; i<payload.length; ++i)
    {
        int add = payload[i];

        for(int bit=7; bit>=0; --bit)
        {
            int b = (add >>> bit) & 1;

            byte newByte = (byte)((image[offset] & 0xFE) | b );

            int swappedbyte = swapLsb(b, image[imageCursor]);


            image[imageCursor] = swappedbyte;


            //increment the image cursor so that we mvoe to the next RGB component
            imageCursor++;

        }
    }
    return image;
}

public int swapLsb(int bitToHide, int byt) {
    //print 'flipping bits'
    int lsb = getLSB(byt);


    if(bitToHide != lsb)
        if(bitToHide ==0)
            byt &= ~ 0x1;
        else
            byt |= 0x1;


    return byt;
}

public int getLSB(int intValue)
{
    return intValue & 0x1;
}
//save the new image to file
public void saveImage(int[] pixels) throws IOException {


    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(this.image.getWidth(), this.image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    WritableRaster raster = (WritableRaster) image.getRaster();

    raster.setPixels(0,0,this.image.getWidth(),this.image.getHeight(),pixels);



    //now write to file
    ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", new File("msg.bmp"));
}



public void encodePayload(int[] msg, int[] cover){

}
//useful for converting java's default signed byte to unsigned byte
protected static int unsignedToBytes(byte b) {
    return b & 0xFF;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Steganography steganography = new Steganography("hello", "image.bmp");


   steganography.encode();

    steganography = new Steganography("this", "msg.bmp");

    steganography.decode();
}
```

}

Comment: and what am I to do with it?? this is like "look gys the marvelous thing I created; now I'm dropping off to you to complete it" - like I said before cut it into three parts test each one and if it doesnt work drop it off here - the part not the whole program

Comment: Is msg.bmp a valid image when you open it up in an image viewer?